# jquery, how to access page with certain tab page via external hyperlink?

Tags: jquery

I have this coding. I want to be able to access say Data Extraction page given a hyperlink. What would i have to add?

thanks
Gordon

```
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-instr"  >Instructions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-documentation"  >Documentation</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#tabs-step1"  >Data Extraction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-support">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-user"   >User Info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-instr"></div>
                    <div id="tabs-documentation"></div>
        <div id="tabs-support"></div>
        <div id="tabs-user"></div>
        <div id="tabs-step1"></div>
      </div>
<script>
            $.get("cgi_scripts/main_userinfo.cgi",function(data){$("#tabs-user").html(data)});
            $.get("cgi_scripts/main_faqpage.cgi",function(data1){$("#tabs-support").html(data1)});
            $.get("cgi_scripts/main_intro_page.cgi",function(data2){$("#tabs-instr").html(data2)});
            $.get("cgi_scripts/main_documentation.cgi",function(data2){$("#tabs-documentation").html(data2)});            
            </script>
```

Comment: i'm confused.. what do you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is a jQuery history plugin. 
Using this plugin it allows you to go to the Data Extraction page with a link like http://server/page#tabs-step1

There are a couple of them available. This seems to be a good one: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the hash value to the href of an anchor like this:

On page 1:

```
<a href='secondPage.html#TheIDofTheContainer'>Go to a specific section on page 2</a>
```

Read more about deep links and ajax [here](http://blog.onthewings.net/2009/04/08/deep-linking-for-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote, I'd throw the script block in a document.ready().  $(function(){}) if you prefer.

jQuery-ui tabs will auto-number the tab IDs it generates:

> Tabs created dynamically using .tabs( "add", ... ) are given an id of
>   ui-tabs-NUM, where NUM is an auto-incrementing id. If you use this
>   naming convention for your own elements, you may encounter problems

I recommend inspecting a generated page and looking for a ID=ui-tabs-###  for the tab that you want, and then creating a link like XGreen mentioned.

```
> <a href='secondPage.html#TheIDofTheContainer'>Go to a specific section
> on page 2</a>
```

just change the #TheIDofTheContainer to the jQuery-ui tabs generated ID.